# Foundation CSS & jQuery Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, jquery-select2

I'm trying to integrate jQuery Select2 with Zurb Foundation CSS and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I need the ability to specify an element to use for storing the selected choices for a multi-select. This element needs to be separate than the element that contains the input search box.

The image below shows two Foundation CSS rows, each row has two columns (except the header row "Country"). A label on the left most column and an input on the right most column. Right now the image below is NOT integrated with Select2.

[image]

I'm trying to implement Select2 in a way where it will display just like the below screenshot. (Note: I obviously manually edited the HTML to display in this format).

[image]

The final HTML structure that I'm trying to achieve is below.

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi row">
<ul class="select2-choices">
<li class="select2-search-choice"></li>
...
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns">my label</div>
<div class="small-9 columns">
<div class="select2-search-field"></div>
```

My question is, how can achieve the layout that's in the second image by specifically telling jQuery Select2 where to place the list of selected choices and where to place the search box?

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the end of my question so it's explaining exactly what I want to get done.

Answer (score 2):

There have been a few people who have already put in some effort at integrating foundation5 and select2. Perhaps cviebrock's gist may be some help? https://gist.github.com/cviebrock/8056741.

If you are looking for an alternative try. Roy McKenzie's foundation specific plugin: http://roymckenzie.github.io/foundation-select/